# Reverse "Add to Home Screen" function

Tags: iphone, ipad, printing

When a webapp is saved as a "Add to Home Screen" app and an icon is created on the ipad or iphone. Is there a way in HTML that can force the application with its current view/state to be opened in Mobile Safari?

The idea behind this is to allow the AirPrint functionality to print in Mobile Safari.

Also would this work if the webapp was wrapped in PhoneGap or some other App wrapper?

Thanks
D

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way in HTML that can force the application with its current view/state to be opened in Mobile Safari?

No. You can't transfer (`UIWebView`) state like this between running apps. You could launch Safari with a particular URL, but that's about it.